# Preparing Data for keras with inputs of varying length strings of DNA

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a model to which I feed DNA sequences (as strings that look like "ATGGATGC..." that I converted to [1,2,3,3,1,2,3,4...]) and have it output 0 if the model thinks the sequence is not a protein and 1 if it thinks it is.

I have prepared 11000 sequences tagged either as 0 or 1 for training.

I am very new to deeplearning, and I am trying to get my data to work on a deeplearning model, but it doesn't work and I can't really understand why. One problem might be that The tutorial said it was best to normalize the data, but my dna sequences are all of variable lenghts.

here's what I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(numSequences, numLabels, epochs=3)
```

where numSequences is an array [[1,2,3,4,2,3,2,1....][1,2,3,2,1,...],...] containing the different DNA sequences of varying length converted into numbers
and numLabels is the corresponding labels [0 or 1]. But it doesn't do anything, i get ValueError: failed to convert a numpy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing the Flatten() layer into an input layer. Then specifying the shape of your inputs. For example:

```
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape = (25,25, 1)))
```

**Note that the shape in my example will not match yours. You will need to specify your shape.